# How to prevent updating Array Values in an Object from another Object Array when both the objects belongs to same List

Tags: angular

I am trying to add some survey type of questions with RadioButton, DropDown fields on Tabs. But when I'm adding tabs and answering questions on Tab 1 which are automatically reflecting on Tab 2.

I think Due to references Whatever the updates we are doing on Question List of Tab 1 on Tab 1 screen which are reflecting on Tab 2 Questions list on Tab 2 Screen.

I have Added Models like below.
//Tab Models

```
interface IGuaranteeDetails{
    GuaranteeId,
    TypeofGuarantee,
    Amount,
    Supplier,
    QuestionList?: IElcQuestionViewModel[]
}
```

//Questions Model

```
interface IElcQuestionViewModel
{
    QuestionId,
    Answer.
    HelpText,
    InfoButton,
    InputType,
    DataType
}
```

`this.ElcQuestionsVM = GetQuestionsList();` // This View model is coming from API on page load.

I have a addNewGuaranteeMethod which add Tabs this method calls on Add guarantee button.

```
addNewGuaranteeTab()
{   
    var GuaranteeTab = <IGuaranteeDetails>
        {
         GuaranteeId = null, 
         TypeofGuarantee = null,
         Amount=null,
         Supplier=null,
         QuestionList: this.ElcQuestionsVM
        }
    GuaranteesList.push(GuaranteeTab);
}
```

On the UI I have a *ngFor for generating Tabs and one more *ngFor I have for generation Questions Dynamically inside Every tab.

```
<Tab *ngFor="let T of GuaranteesList">
//Tabs other fields code
    <div *ngFor="let question of QuestionList">
        //Question Code goes here
    </div>
</tab>
```

## Problem is

When I add Tab 1: For single Tab it is working fine, I could able to answer Yes/No Question, I could able to select Dropdown values it stores in that perticult tab ngModel object.

But when I add Tab 2 then automatically whatever the Question which I have answerd on Tab 1 with answers automatically populating on Tab 2. It should not happen like this. When I enter Tab 2 everything should be blank. As per my understanding Due to references it is happening.

## Solutions I have tried.

I have used {...ElcQuestionsVM}, [...ElcQuestionsVM]

I expect the one object changes should not update in other object.

I expect the one object changes should not update in other object.